# Background height full screen while scrolling

Tags: html, css, scroll, background-color

I have the following nesting:

```
body {
    app-root {
        app-block-page {
            app-block-content {
                div.wrapper {
                    *content*
                }
            }
        }
     }
}
```

`body` has `width:100%` and `height:100%`

`app-block-page` has `width:100%`, `height:100%`, `background-color: red` and `display:block`

`app-block-content` has `padding:100px 0`, `display:flex`, `justify-content:center` and `align-items:center`

`div.wrapper` has `width:80%`

**Result**

[image]

**Question**

How to make background-color to not be scrolled?

I need only form to be scrolled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use `position:fixed` on `app-block-page`

> **position: fixed;** 
>   An element with position: fixed; is positioned
>   relative to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same
>   place even if the page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left
>   properties are used to position the element.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: Set, but now I can't scroll

Comment: Take out the `app-block-content` and put it next to the `app-block-page`